# Vue3 Composition API Apollo Client userMutation() in watch function

Tags: vue.js, apollo-client, watch, vue-composition-api

I am using Vue3 with the composition API and Apollo client.
I use an `useQuery()` function to query some data. With it I use a watcher like `watch(result, (newVal) => {})`

What I want to do is, using the `useMutation()` inside this watcher. But it does not work at all.

This is the error message I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Apollo client with id default not found. Use provideApolloClient() if you are outside of a component setup.
at resolveClient (useApolloClient.ts:68:13)
at mutate (useMutation.ts:78:20)
at VerifyEmailView.vue:31:9
at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155:22)
at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164:21)
at job (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1776:17)
at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155:36)
at flushJobs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:388:17)
```

This is the code I use

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { useMutation, useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { useSessionStore } from '@/stores/SessionStore'
import UPDATE_NFCUSER_EMAIL_VERIFICATION_CODE from '@/graphql/UpdateNfcUserEmailVeriifcationCode.mutation.gql'
import GET_NFCUSER_ID_BY_EMAIL_VERIFICATION_CODE from '@/graphql/GetNfcUserIdByEmailVerificationCode.query.gql'
import { watch, ref } from 'vue'

const sessionStore = useSessionStore()
const router = useRouter()
const route = useRoute()
const route_verification_code = route.params.verification_code
const code_not_verified = ref(false)
const { result } = useQuery(GET_NFCUSER_ID_BY_EMAIL_VERIFICATION_CODE, {
  verification_code: route_verification_code,
})

watch(result, (newVal) => {
  if (newVal?.getNfcUserIdByEmailVerificationCode?.status === 200) {
    const nfc_user_id = newVal?.getNfcUserIdByEmailVerificationCode?.nfc_user_id

    if (nfc_user_id) {
      console.log('Verification Code is valid')

      sessionStore.setCurrentUserVerified(true)
      sessionStore.setCurrentNfcUserId(nfc_user_id)

      const { mutate } = useMutation(UPDATE_NFCUSER_EMAIL_VERIFICATION_CODE)

      mutate({
        nfcUserId: nfc_user_id,
      })
    } else {
      console.log('Code is not correct')
      code_not_verified.value = true
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Code is not correct')
    code_not_verified.value = true
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you add any of the error messages that show up in the console or Vue dev tools?

Comment: @StephenGilboy Sure. I added the console error message. Btw, I am inside a `<script setup>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error it seems you would want to set the mutation variable outside of the `watch()` the same way you're using the query;

```
const { mutate: updateNfcUserEmailVerificationCode } = useMutation(UPDATE_NFCUSER_EMAIL_VERIFICATION_CODE);


// watch function
updateNfcUserEmailVerificationCode({ nfcUserId: nfc_user_id });
```

If you did want to use it in the `watch()` function it looks like you'll have to use the Apollo client directly: https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-option/mutations.html

```
// watch function
this.$apollo.mutate({
  mutation: UPDATE_NFCUSER_EMAIL_VERIFICATION_CODE,
  variables: { nfcUserId: nfc_user_id },
});
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping. It got me on the right track. You must use `apolloClient` inside `watch()` like you would outside of `setup()`. I followed this instructions: https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/setup.html The difference to your link is, that yours is for the options API, but I am using the composition API. But anyways, your answer was the correct one.